# Best practices using the Page Object Mode

Tags: selenium, kotlin, cucumber, pageobjects

I'm trying to figure out the best way of making my Page Objects simple, and whether to put absolutely all logic elsewhere. And whether all Selenium code/functionality should be in the Page Object, or in the Step Definition methods I use to access it.

I have the following structure:

Cucumber.feature files

```
Given blablabla
```

Java/Kotlin step definitions

```
@Given("^blablabla$") {

}
```

And the page object files

```
fun getOwnerFields(): MutableList<WebElement> {
   return driver.findElements(By.if("owner-fields")
}
```

As a simple example.

Now, what I cannot come to an agreement with myself on, or find much of other's opinions about, is:

Should I do page actions - for instance, a button click, in the Step Definition class OR in the Page Object?

This:

```
@Given("^I click on the Next button$") {
    startPage.nextButton().click()
}

PO:
fun nextButton(): WebElement {
    return driver.findElement(By.id("next-button")
}
```

Or:v

```
@Given("^I click on the Next button$") {
    startPage.clickNextButton()
}

PO:
fun clickNextButton(): WebElement {
    return driver.findElement(By.id("next-button").click()
}
```

I've tended to think that it's best to keep all the page and selenium code in the Page Object. But in cases like this, it makes the PO bigger, because I'll need different methods for clicking, checking for visibility, counting etc. While if all this is done in the step definitions, the PO can practically contain nothing but getters and setters for the page elements.

Anyone got any light to shed? I know it's not THAT important, but I tend to be quite occupied with the best and/or cleanest way of organizing my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed opinion based question. It depends on the bunch of factors including what your app can and how flexible the user interaction is assumed to be.

As to me since your core abstraction is assumed to be on Gherkin statement level I would say I does not make sense to put a lot of abstraction on lower levels.

Button is not that good example actually because normally you only can click  it so there would hardly be other types of interactions. But for other elements my choice would definitely fall on your first approach.

Such the approach would let you to concentrate on the logic that is specific for the step so that being in the step definition you can clearly see what's happening there without extra navigation through the classes.

Comment: I tend to agree. Also, I agree that in the button example it doesn't matter with regards to more/less code. But I'm also taking into account the tidyness, and whether or not having selenium functionality in the step definition supports that. Thanks for the opinion :-)

Comment: Since you've got something to say about this: What's your thoughs about using PageFactory  and FindBy in the PO classes, for creating the WebElement variables. More tidy, even though it results in more lines of code? I sort of like it, but the increased number of code lines at the beginning of the class bothers me a bit.

Comment: You mean what to use? either findby or pagefactory approach?

Comment: I've used Page Factory, creating the WebElements with "@FindBy(id="login"), WebElement login.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, in your case it's not that important. However, consider using domain language in your Step Definitions, instead of exposing low level of details.

Let me give you an example:

In your test class:

```
lateinit var driver: WebDriver
lateinit var homePage: HomePage

@Before
public void init() {
    driver = ChromeDriver()
    homePage = HomePage(driver)
}

@Given("^I am on the home page$") {
    homepage.open()
}

@When("^I enter my credentials$") {
    homePage.login()
}

@Then("^I am on the dashboard$") { 
    /*
      Here you create a Dashboard page and verify the title for example
    */
}
```

In your PO class:

```
class HomePage(val driver: WebDriver) {
    @FindBy(css = "username")
    private lateinit var username: WebElement

    @FindBy(id = "password")
    private lateinit var password: WebElement

    @FindBy(id = "submit")
    private lateinit var submitButton: WebElement


    init {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this)
    }

    fun open() {
        driver.get("WEBSITE_UNDER_TEST")
    }

    fun login() {
        username.sendKeys("foo")
        password.sendKeys("bar")
        submitButton.click()
    }
}
```

As you can see, you are just using your PO:s public API:s to perform actions on the pages.
This is only one way of abstracting your code to make it more maintainable in the long run.

If you want to learn more, I recommend this video from Gáspár Nagy: https://youtu.be/BbAuS-48XbE?t=2153

Getting BDD right is seemingly easy, but in reality it takes practice.